# Single CSV column is using multiple columns in HTML table

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, html-table

After a long journey to figure out how to load .csv files into a table I've run into another issue. One of the columns in my .csv file is splitting into other columns in my HTML table.

Part of the issue was with the file itself, where the content was actually split into other columns. After fixing everything (I left one on purpose), I'm still facing the same problem. It doesn't seem to be a character limit issue as they split after random words each time.

[image]

[image]

The very first entry in the .csv file is an easy example of what's going on. It also isn't everything in that column. The table is being read in through ajax and jQuery with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
      url:"014 - Dark Beginning 1 2004.csv",
      dataType:"text",
      success:function(data)
      {
       var card_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
       var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
       for(var count = 0; count<card_data.length; count++)
       {
        var cell_data = card_data[count].split(",");
        table_data += '<tr>';
        for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++){
         if(count === 0){
          table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';}
            else{
          table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';}
        }
        table_data += '</tr>';
       }
       table_data += '</table>';
       $('#card_table').html(table_data);
      }
     });
    });
    
   });
```

Is this some limit tables innately have or some other issue entirely? I have very minimally changed the CSS for the table solely to make it easier for me to look at for when I get to organizing the page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just splitting the comma string values by comma (`,`) you're splitting the strings in your descriptions values as well. In a csv file, values that might contain the separator (`,` in this case) or other special characters are wrapped by quotes `""`, in your case in the descriptions.

You must not account for any comma that might reside inside a quoted string, as everything written inside account for a single value of a column row.

I would suggest using a library, such as [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) to handle this kind of parsing, as those kind of tasks might take a lot of details into account that you might not want to be troubled with.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. It didn't even cross my mind that would be a problem. I'll definitely take a look at your link because I have quite a few files to go through!

Comment: Don't worry, these things happen when we're talking about files with simple formats and we think we might be able to deal with those ouselves, often they have scenarios we might have not yet imagined we might encounter, and since those formats are standardized, such libraries already know how to deal with all those little details, while also having other useful tools, like configurable return options and batch/chunk loading.

This parser is just an example, you can use anyone you might like.